# Problems with rebuilding Android project in Intellij IDEA 13

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've created a project for Android in Eclipse. It worked, but when I imported the project in Intellij IDEA 13, there appeared a problem.
Maybe I haven't fully tuned IDEA.
My code:

```
package myProject.helpers;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Reasons {

    private static Map<Integer, String> reasons = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    static {
        reasons.put(1, "Test 1");
        reasons.put(3, "Test 2");
        reasons.put(5, "Test 3");
        reasons.put(6, "Test 4");           
    }

    public static String getReasonByNumber(int reason) {
        return reasons.get(reason);
    }

    public static int getReasonNumberByText(String reason) {
        int reasonIndex = 0;        
        for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : reasons.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(reason)) {
                reasonIndex = entry.getKey();
            }
        }       
        return reasonIndex;
    }

    public static List<String> getAll() {
        return new ArrayList<String>(reasons.values());
    }
}
```

And logs for Error:

```
java: illegal character: '\ufeff'
java: class, interface, or enum expected
```